# Is there another way to create objects in java rather than using the "new" keyword?

Tags: java

One of my lecturer said that there are some other ways to create/instantiate objects in Java rather than using the "new" keyword. If it is possible, please guide me how to do so?

Comment: Look into reflection. Also String literals.

Comment: also primitives - maybe those are 'objects'

Comment: Deserialization is another way.

Comment: What about asking a factory to get an instance of a class.

Comment: @David: that's not an instantiation in itself though. The factory will use one of the methods described above.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like more of an interview question but I will still answer it :)

Reflection is one way to create instance of an object. You can `Class.forName("abc.de.FGH").newInstance()` to create an instance

The other way is to use deserialization assuming an object is serialized.

```
new ObjectInputStream(anInputStream ).readObject();
```

One other way I could think of it is cloning.

```
Object otherObject = mainObject.clone();
```

Primitive Types, String Literals are other ways of creating object though they are specific to certain types.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd count autoboxing, as it just e.g. rewrites the code to `Integer.valueOf(foo)`, and `Integer.valueOf` either gets the already-cached `Integer`, which was created with `new`, or creates a fresh `Integer` with `new`.  String literals are a good example, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could create object using reflection or with autoboxing mechanism or any other literals built in to language.

```
String x = "abc";
int[] y = {1, 2, 3}
Object z = classObject.newInstnce();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, objects are instantiated using the "new" keyword. But this doesn't mean, they can be instantiated only this way.

Have a look at the following code(Java):

```
public class SimpleClass {

    public static SimpleClass instantiateAnObjectForMe() {

        return new SimpleClass();      

    } 
}
```

And then somewhere else in your project, You can create the instance of the class by calling the static method I wrote above like so:

```
SimpleClass simpleObject = SimpleClass.instantiateAnObjectForMe();
```

I hope you get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

One example is `Object.class.newInstance()`. There are more complex ways using java reflection, [here is one of many tutorials](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/constructors.html).

Comment: Edit the title of page( pointed by the link ): Yor page says **Contructors**. _s_ is missing